# show Json object in view

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC method that run webAPI and returns some list of question and answers as a json format. I try to show these data in my View. but it shows them as json format and not show my view at all. I like to show the faq under my table.
This is my controller method:

```
    [Route("showcontact")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ShowContact(int loanId)
    {
        string json = string.Empty;
        List<Faq> FaqObject = null;
        var responseApi = await httpClient.GetAsync(string.Format("{0}/{1}", CommonApiBaseUrlValue, "faqs"));
        if (responseApi.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            json = responseApi.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            FaqObject = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Faq>>(json);
        }

        var response = new
        {
            success = FaqObject != null,
            data = FaqObject
        };
        return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is my view:

```
@model Carfinance.Loans.Web.ViewModels.HelpCenterViewModel
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/HelpCenter/HelpCenter.js"></script>

<table>
<tr><td><h2>Contact Us</h2></td></tr>
<tr><td>FUNDING SPECIALIST:</td><td>PHONE & EMAIL:</td><td>HOURS:</td></tr>   
</table>
```

and this is my js file to show json content, but it is not going to this file at all as even the alert is not showing.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 alert("test");

        var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();

        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            //headers: { "__RequestVerificationToken": token },
            url: '/showcontact',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {

                jQuery.parseJSON(result);

            },
            error: function () { debugger; alert('failure'); }
        });
```

});

This is what I am getting instead of view:

```
 {
  success: true,
  data: [
    {
      Id: 1,
      Category: "General",
      Question: "Question1",
      Answer: "Answer1"
      },
      {
      Id: 2,
      Category: "Stipulation related",
      Question: "Question2",
      Answer: "Answer2"
      }
      ]
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the data, now you just need a place to put it!

From your code, I see that your `View` does not have a specified element to display the data you are retrieving from your API.

Try iterating through your results in your Ajax call to build a table of the data you just requested.

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behavior, since you are returning an instance of `JsonResult` instead of `ViewResult`.

You need to rethink your approach and define what do you want to that Action return: a Json object or a rendered view?
If you go for the first choice, your ajax callback must handle the json data and use javascript to populate the DOM.

If you want the rendered view, you must use `return View(model)` and you can use use Razor to define the template for the view.

Answer (score 0):

Change `return Json()` into `return View()`. This will let MVC look up a view template to return. The Json you retrieved can be passed as model (by putting it straight to the view: `return View(json)` or by putting it in the [ViewBag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx).